# Maintain 4 digits in database INT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to maintain 4 digits in a column in MySQL. E.g. 0003, 1234, 0059.

Currently I have it as INT. But other than VARCHAR is it possible to store the numbers as INT and still maintain 4 numbers? So basically if I add `0005` it should store as `0005`? How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why is it imperative to _store_ the leading zeros _in the database_?

Comment: @VolkerK thanks. It's a serial code that I'm storing here. I feel it's better if the serial is stored as it should be rather than filling up the zeros by the code?

Comment: Are you going to do maths with the serial number? No. So don't store it as a number, store it as a string that happens to contain numbers.

Comment: @DCoder thanks. It does not need to be maths to store / use INT? INT comparisons are faster than varchar comparisons. So posted this question incase if there are any better ways of doing this using INT.

Comment: You're doing premature optimization. If all you're doing 99% of the time is looking up an individual row by its s/n, the performance difference will not be noticeable. Make sure the column is indexed and forget about this.

Comment: @DCoder I'm using a foreign key to do that. That's not an issue here. thanks anyway. :) +1